# How to copy access.log lines by time?

Tags: centos, logs, search

I have a huge webserver access.log in CentOS. I access it over remote VPN so I cant copy the file or read it directly.

I know the specific time in the logs I want to copy, but it is too far back too easily copy a tail of the log to a text file. Here is what a line of the log looks like.

```
10.255.16.203 - - [26/Mar/2014:16:35:13 +0000]
```

*So my question is* : **How can I copy a specific section of a very large log if I know the time strings I want to find?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grep` command is designed to show only matching lines of a given files. With the use of `-C` option it is possible to show not only the matching line(s) but some lines before and after it.

So to have the 3 lines before and after the line you want:

```
$ grep -C 3 "26/Mar/2014:16:35:13 +0000" access.log
```

You can also tune more precisely the number of lines displayed after and/or before the matching lines with the `-A` and `-B` options. In fact `-C 3` is the same as `-A 3 -B 3`.

If there are more than one matching line, then `grep` would display the 3 lines before and after the matched lines block.

Example:

```
$ grep -C 3 "25/Mar/2014:10:40:59 +0100" access.log
10.0.0.44 - httpuse [25/Mar/2014:09:41:17 +0100] "GET /dummy/BIGDummy_133644_1565_DL.xml.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 507 "-" "-"
10.0.0.43 - httpuse [25/Mar/2014:09:59:51 +0100] "GET /dummy/BIGDummy_133647_48267_DL.xml.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 1677 "-" "-"
10.0.0.44 - httpuse [25/Mar/2014:10:40:42 +0100] "GET /dummy/BIGDummy_133664_39603_DL.xml.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 1677 "-" "-"
10.0.0.40 - httpuse [25/Mar/2014:10:40:59 +0100] "GET /dummy/BIGDummy_133664_DL.xml.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 60142 "-" "-"
10.0.0.41 - httpuse [25/Mar/2014:10:40:59 +0100] "GET /dummy/BIGDummy_133667_23124_DL.xml.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 5202 "-" "-"
10.0.0.40 - httpuse [25/Mar/2014:10:43:09 +0100] "GET /dummy/BIGDummy_133668_46_DL.xml.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 445 "-" "-"
10.0.0.42 - httpuse [25/Mar/2014:10:43:10 +0100] "GET /dummy/BIGDummy_133668_4116_DL.xml.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 597 "-" "-"
10.0.0.40 - httpuse [25/Mar/2014:10:43:13 +0100] "GET /dummy/BIGDummy_133665_DL.xml.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 57902 "-" "-"
```

From `man grep`:

```
NAME
   grep, egrep, fgrep - print lines matching a pattern

SYNOPSIS
   grep [options] PATTERN [FILE...]

DESCRIPTION
   Grep  searches  the  named  input  FILEs (or standard input if no files are named,
    or the file name - is given) for lines containing a match to the given PATTERN.
   By default, grep prints the matching lines.

OPTIONS
    -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
            Print  NUM  lines  of  trailing context after matching lines.
            Places a line containing -- between contiguous groups of matches.

    -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
            Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.
            Places a line containing --  between  contiguous  groups  of matches.

    -C NUM, --context=NUM
            Print  NUM  lines  of  output  context.
            Places a line containing -- between contiguous groups of matches.
```

Comment: Thanks, I would never have got that from the man page description.

Comment: Also `-A` would be useful to copy lines after a specific date and `-B` for before.

Comment: In fact `-C 3` is the same as `-A 3 -B 3`. But sure, with the options you can tune the context display more precisely.